# Offline client and messages to azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I'm playing around with windows azure and I would like to build a clouded server application that receives messages from many different clients, such as mobile and desktop.
I would like to build the client so that they work while in "offline-mode", i.e. I would like the client to build up a local queue of messages that are sent to the azure server as soon as they get online.

Can I accomplish this using wcf and/or azure queing mechanism, so that I don't have to worry about whether the client is online or offline when I write the code?

Answer (score 2):

You won't need queuing in the cloud to accomplish this. For the client app to be "offline enabled" you need to do queuing on the client. For this there are many options, a local database, xml files, etc. Whenever the app senses network availability you can upload your queue to Azure. And yes, you can use WCF for that.

For the client queue/sync stuff you could take a look at [the Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a great need for the queue so far.  Maybe it's just that I'm not seeing it in my app view.  Could also be that the data you can store in the queue is minimal.  You basically store short text strings (like record ids), and then you have to do something with the ID when you pull it from the queue, such as look it up, delete it, whatever.

In my app, I didn't use the queue at all, just as Peter suggests.  I wrote directly to table storage (accessed via it's REST interface using StorageClient) from the client. If you want to look at a concrete example, take a look at http://www.netalerts.mobi/traffic. Like you, I wanted to learn Azure so I built a small web site.

There's a worker_role that wakes up every 60 seconds.  Using one thread, it retrieves any new data from it's source (screen scraping a web page).  New entries are stored directly in table storage (no need for a queue).  Another thread deletes entries in table storage that are older than a specified threshold (there's no issue with running multiple threads against table storage). And then I'm working on the third thread which is designed to send notifications to handheld devices.

The app itself is a web_role, obviously.